Оперативная память истощается если выполнять FFMPEG в цикле
Запускаю скрипт python.py
В нем:
for file in glob.glob(patch+'*.*'):
   subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg ***

Возможно ошибаюсь, но наблюдаю следующее.
Скрипт перебирает содержимо каталога, допустим в каталоге один видеофайл. Тут вопросов нет, но если видеофайлов допустим 10, которые необходимо преобразовать.
То с каждым последующим, который ffmpeg берет в работу. Объем свободной, оперативной памяти все меньше и меньше.
Если изначально, при работе с первым файлом из 3.5гб свободной памяти, оставалось 3гб, то на втором уже 2.5, а на третьем 1.5 и все меньше и меньше.
Быть может кто сталкивался с этим, в чем тут дело. Почему с завершением преобразования одного файла, память не освобождается. Не освобождается до тех пор, по как не пройдет по всем файлом что цикл прочитал...
Как чистить память после каждого файла? Тут же скорость кодирования падает по мере используемой памяти...
OC.Ubuntu

Любопытно какой ответ будет в консоле, когда память исчерпается...
Пока писал пост, до 950мб упала

Если одновременно работает только один ffmpeg, который затем завершает свою работу, то потреблению памяти взяться в принципе неоткуда. Поэтому проверяйте какие-нибудь tmpfs на предмет завалявшихся в них мусорных файлов, например

Ну и на скриншоте написано что доступно 5 гигов, поэтому не вижу поводов для беспокойства

А колонка free? Free это доступно, и ее все меньше и меньше. А used, в работе, все растет

Ну и хорошо что меньше, незанятая память - бесполезная память. Система использует всю имеющуюся оперативку для кэширования часто используемых файлов, чтобы всё работало шустрее, это нормально

Хз, но на 950мб. FFMPEG завершил преобразование, не обработав целиком. Через screen запустил, историю автоматом очистил. Придется логи вести и смотреть что та произошло...

available это сколько доступно с учетом использования операционной. Оно неизменно, free это сколько доступно в данный момент, сколько не использованной. Total это сколько вообще в железе установлено. А used, это сколько используется пользователем его программами которые он запусти.

available очень даже изменно, вы где-то чуши начитались

Прогоните тот же цикл в баше. Воспроизведётся?

Процессы создаются сразу (не блокируя друг друга) и работают параллельно поэтому и память улетучивается, проще решить через рекурсию с ожиданием завершения, но у рекурсии свои минусы.

В качестве идеи. Во-первых, из такого огрызка кода ничего толком понять невозможно. Да и замеры эти... под сомнением. Кто это меряет? Как и что? Можно попробовать выполнять не непосредственно в цикле for, а с использованием посредника - функции, запускающей ffmpeg. Идея в том, чтоб попытаться припахать мусорщик Питона для уничтожения результатов работы функции.
